# How to run kivy 1.9.1 app in Kivy launcher?

Tags: android, kivy

I wrote a simple app with Kivy 1.9.1-dev. When I want to test it using Kivy launcher on an Andriod 2.4 device I get

```
[WARNING           ] stderr: Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old. (You have 1.9.0, but the application requires 1.9.1)
```

and the app doesn't work. 
Is it possible to test apps developed with 1.9.1 on kivy launcher?

The kivy launcher log is:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/wp/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-07-01_4.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.0
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Apr  2 2015, 13:52:41) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 173 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/data/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: pygame
[INFO              ] Window: Provider: pygame
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0 17.01214>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL vendor <NVIDIA Corporation>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL renderer <NVIDIA Tegra>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max size <4096>
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] Shader: fragment shader: <14 lines, 0 errors.>
[INFO              ] Shader: vertex shader: <23 lines, 0 errors.>
[INFO              ] Support: Android install hooks
[INFO              ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 108, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     WPApp().run()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 797, in run
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 594, in load_kv
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1749, in load_file
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1796, in load_string
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1185, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1284, in parse
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1197, in execute_directives
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py", line 127, in require
[WARNING           ] stderr: Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old. (You have 1.9.0, but the application requires 1.9.1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does it think it needs 1.9.1? Did you put this in a requires field?

Comment: Not in my code. It seems it is in the __init__ form python-for-android. Or maybe is there a default value I have to override in the config file (android.txt)?

Comment: Can you post the code for your app?

Comment: Sure, but there is no "import kivy; kivy.require('1.9.1')" in my .py files and in one of my .kv files (the app .kv's) there is only "#:kivy 1.9.0"

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, you'd need to build your own version of kivy launcher using python-for-android (it has arguments to specify this).

However, if you post your code we can check if it actually needs 1.9.1, and work out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify kivy version at the beginning of your code like this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your kivy version:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade kivy
```

then add:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("versionkivy") #kivy.require("1.11.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You write in topmost of your code -

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")
```